# Jackson Inheritance

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

Can't seem to figure this out. I keep getting various errors so I'll just write this with the current error I'm getting from Jackson.

```
public class ResponseDetail {
    private Response response;
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResponseTypeOne.class, name = "ResponseTypeOne"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResponseTypeTwo.class, name = "ResponseTypeTwo"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResponseTypeThree.class, name = "ResponseTypeThree")
})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class Response {
}
```

In other packages I have these three:

```
public class ResponseTypeOne extends Response {
     private Integer status;
}
public class ResponseTypeTwo extends Response {
    private String message;
}
public class ResponseTypeThree extends Response {
     private String value;
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.services.models.Response]: missing type id property '@type' (for POJO property 'response')
```

I have tried various iterations of this `@JsonTypeInfo` with various `includes` and various `property`'s also with `Id.CLASS` with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare how the type should be recognized.

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "@ttype")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResponseTypeOne.class, name = "ResponseTypeOne"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResponseTypeTwo.class, name = "ResponseTypeTwo"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResponseTypeThree.class, name = "ResponseTypeThree")
})

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class Response {
   @JsonProperty("@ttype")
   public abstract String getChildType();
}
```

And in child types do like below:

```java
   @JsonTypeName("ResponseTypeOne")
    public class ResponseTypeOne extends Response {
        @Override
        public String getChildType() {
            return "ResponseTypeOne";
        }
    }
```

And incoming json should be like below to enable jackson to find the correct child implementation:

```json
{
  //some attributes of child Response
  "@ttype": "ResponseTypeOne"
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering! This gives me `Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.services.resolve.models.authentication. ResponseTypeOne]: missing type id property '@ttype'`

Comment: @user11475606 In serializing or deserializing?

Comment: Deserializing json coming in to Java (comments have to be 15 characters in length on stackoverflow)

Comment: @user11475606 Did you put `@ttype` member in json object comming to server? And could you please show the json?

Comment: I'm going to have to configure the app a little to get the JSON response logging to the console. In `ResponseTypeOne` I have this `@JsonProperty("@ttype")
    @Override
    public String getChildType() {
        return "ResponseTypeOne";
    }`

Comment: @user11475606 The server-side is ok. You need to put `@ttype` attribute in the incomming json.

Comment: @user11475606 I updated my answer putting the json like

Comment: I see. I appreciate it but I cannot change the JSON that is coming back unfortunately. I still have a fall back which is to flatten the object map and remove the inheritance.

Comment: @user11475606 If you don't have control on incoming json so you need to implement a custom jackson deserializer